# set drawable to some part text of android textview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I have text in textview "To get free recharge use "80FC" promo code.

I want to set and rectangle to background of 80FC text.

Please help!!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Oveflow. Please visit the help center and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what to ask and how.

Comment: you can use SpannableString for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
TextView TV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mytextview01);

Spannable wordtoSpan = new SpannableString("To get free recharge use \"80FC\" promo code.");        

wordtoSpan.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 37, 41, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

TV.setText(wordtoSpan);
```

Code above should set a background of `80FC` to red. I might mistaken with the index of start and end. You can play with it, and get the correct result.